# Ruby on Rails - Two different Edit pages and forms. How to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, view, edit

Well I need 2 pages. One to edit some information and other to just edit the password of the user.

I have the first working already and ignoring the password check. code below:

Controller:

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @role = @user.role
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      #sucesso
      flash[:success] = "Dados Editados com sucesso!"
      redirect_to "/user_home/#{@user.id}"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Model:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, on: :create
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, on: :update, allow_blank: true;
```

Now how can i implement a second edit just for the password? new routes? new views?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***One idea is to show passwords in your edit form also because you are allowing blank submit of the attributes so they are updated only when present.***

***You also didn't specify if you are using `gem "devise"` because that changes what i wrote below.***

---

### If you really want to do the second view here is some help:

In routes.rb you need a new route to show the form with just passwords.

```rb
resources :users do
  member do
    get :edit_password
    put :update_password
  end
end
```

In your users_controller.rb add the following method:

```rb
def edit_password
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update_password
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  # also in here i'm calling the authenticate method that usually is present in bcrypt.
  if user and user.authenticate(params[:old_password])
    if params[:password] == params[:password_confirmation]
      user.password = BCrypt::Password.create(params[:password])
      if user.save!
        redirect_to edit_password_url, notice: "Password changed"
      end
    else
        redirect_to edit_password_url, notice: "Incorrect Password."
    end
  else
    redirect_to edit_password_url, notice: "Incorrect Password."
  end
end
```

*NOTE: in the update_password method i'm using authenticate that is present in bcrypt gem. It's recommended to use that. Read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html*

```
# in Gemfile
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

Create a new file views/users/edit_password.html.erb and add the following code:

```rb
<%= form_for @user, url: update_password_user_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :old_password %>
  <%= f.password_field :old_password %>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.submit "Update password" %>
<% end %>
```